# I would also have a translation problem with opecart 3.0.3.3

Tags: opencart

After I changed the language to system-language and I chose the desired language, in the admin part when I want to add products, categories even if I chose only one language it also opens my English. So the error is that although I chose only one language to create products forces me to complete in English.
Error found in '' error '' is:
public_html/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php on line 109
I would be happy if you would help me find a solution for this bag.

Comment: Clean all caches (system, twig, ocmod). And write the full text of your error please. Have you updated your OpenCart recently? Here is nice topic about the similar issue https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=166985

Comment: I clean all cashes , but not working,Yes ,put sticky menu and language extension(created by me)